# O365 Sharepoint Not Registering Group Change

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-365

I've got an Azure AD group called "Employees". It had one member in it.

I added the group to a Document List in SharePoint so everyone in the group would have a certain level of permissions in it.

I then added two other members to the group.

When I do "check permissions" for the first user, it shows that user has permissions to the Document List because of the group.

When I do "check permissions" for either of the other two users it does not show any access.

Its been over an hour and this still hasn't synced or something.

Is there a manual way to make SharePoint refresh its list of groups from Azure AD, or what is the way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this group synced from Active Directory?  If so, you can move the group to an OU that doesn't sync, force sync and check that it's been removed from Azure AD, then add it back and re-sync, and you should see things as you expect.

If its a cloud only group (not synced), it is a little trickier.  If you don't see your users (and you validate that are in the same group) after 24 hours I would put in a ticket.  This goes for a synced group too if you did the above and it still doesn't show.  Microsoft can run a backend job that syncs data from Azure AD to the other services.  Sometimes things get "stuck" between the services.

Comment: It took 6 hrs, but this eventually did sync over. I'm cloud only, so I don't have the option of removing / resyncing. I did end up opening a ticket anyway though, since it is VERY common for me to have large delays before permissions of any type are applied in SharePoint.  Hopefully they can figure out what is going on.

In the meantime, I'm accepting your answer because its a very good outline of the options.